# How and where on a server do I pull git with a Drupal site, by using SSH

Tags: git, drupal, ssh, terminal

Our company has a Drupal site on a server. Sadly the experienced developer has left the company and now I (junior Dev) have to fix some minor things. But nobody here can answer my questions sadly.

So, it goes as follows:
I have cloned this master-branch of the site to my computer in 'Sourcetree' . I made a change to 1 file. I committed and pushed it in 'Sourcetree'. But now I have to go into the server using the command line and do a GIT pull there. That's what I've been told.

But where, in which folder, exactly do I have to go before performing a 'GIT pull' command?

Comment: Where is your Drupal site stored on the server's file system? This might be a good place to start looking. Check for a hidden .git directory there.

Comment: Edited: Thank you! I searched with the command "ls -a" in some folders until I found a hidden file and folder called .git . At first I performed a git pull but that didn't work immediately because I had 2 branches. After searching the net I did a "git pull origin master" to address only the correct branch et voila. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody has a similar question in the future: here is the anwer (based on the comments below the question):

- search with the command "`ls -a`" in some folders until you find a hidden file and folder called `.git` (to find out where your Drupal site is stored on the server's file system). Then change to that directory.
- if you perform a `git pull` that may not work immediately if you have multiple branches.
- perform a "`git pull origin master`" to address only the correct branch et voilà!
- That's it!